# Is there any solution to resend OTP using Firebase in iOS?

Tags: object

In this link, https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/phone-auth send phone number verification code is provided.But is there any solution to resend OTP in the same number in iOS.

Answer (score 3):

I have also wanted this, but on testing and checking [example firebase app](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/bd85f550931f89c82ebf77d53cbff049bfef9be8/Example/Auth/SwiftSample/ViewController.swift), resending was same as generating it first time i.e `PhoneAuthProvider.provider().verifyPhoneNumber`(Swift) unlike android where in we send resend token.